# subset dataframe pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, subset

**Updated code based on provided answer**

The implemented solution isn't subsetting the original dataframe.

```
    In [1]: thresh_eval.head()

    Out[1]:
        WDIR    WSPD    GDR     GST     GTIME
    TX_DTTM                     
    2010-01-01 05:50:00     235     10.9    238     13.4    540
    2010-01-02 00:20:00     329     10.6    NaN     NaN     NaN
    2010-01-02 00:30:00     329     10.8    NaN     NaN     NaN
    2010-01-02 00:40:00     329     12.1    NaN     NaN     NaN
    2010-01-02 00:50:00     332     12.2    330     14.8    46

    In [2]: len(thresh_eval)

    Out[2]: 5503

    In [3]: unique(thresh_eval.index.date)

    Out[3]:

    array([datetime.date(2010, 1, 1), datetime.date(2010, 1, 2),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 3), datetime.date(2010, 1, 4),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 6), datetime.date(2010, 1, 8),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 9), datetime.date(2010, 1, 12),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 16), datetime.date(2010, 1, 17),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 18), datetime.date(2010, 1, 21),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 22), datetime.date(2010, 1, 23),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 24), datetime.date(2010, 1, 25),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 26), datetime.date(2010, 1, 27),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 29), datetime.date(2010, 1, 30),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 31), datetime.date(2010, 2, 1),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 2), datetime.date(2010, 2, 3),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 4), datetime.date(2010, 2, 5),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 6), datetime.date(2010, 2, 7),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 9), datetime.date(2010, 2, 10),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 11), datetime.date(2010, 2, 12),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 13), datetime.date(2010, 2, 14),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 15), datetime.date(2010, 2, 16),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 17), datetime.date(2010, 2, 18),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 22), datetime.date(2010, 2, 25),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 26), datetime.date(2010, 2, 27),
           datetime.date(2010, 2, 28), datetime.date(2010, 3, 2),
           datetime.date(2010, 3, 3), datetime.date(2010, 3, 12),
           datetime.date(2010, 3, 13), datetime.date(2010, 3, 14),
           datetime.date(2010, 3, 15), datetime.date(2010, 3, 18),
           datetime.date(2010, 3, 21), datetime.date(2010, 3, 22),
           datetime.date(2010, 3, 23), datetime.date(2010, 3, 26),
           datetime.date(2010, 3, 27), datetime.date(2010, 3, 28),
           datetime.date(2010, 3, 29), datetime.date(2010, 3, 30),
           datetime.date(2010, 4, 9), datetime.date(2010, 4, 17),
           datetime.date(2010, 4, 18), datetime.date(2010, 4, 25),
           datetime.date(2010, 4, 26), datetime.date(2010, 4, 27),
           datetime.date(2010, 4, 28), datetime.date(2010, 5, 3),
           datetime.date(2010, 5, 8), datetime.date(2010, 5, 9),
           datetime.date(2010, 5, 17), datetime.date(2010, 5, 24),
           datetime.date(2010, 5, 25), datetime.date(2010, 5, 26),
           datetime.date(2010, 6, 2), datetime.date(2010, 6, 3),
           datetime.date(2010, 6, 6), datetime.date(2010, 6, 7),
           datetime.date(2010, 6, 16), datetime.date(2010, 6, 28),
           datetime.date(2010, 7, 2), datetime.date(2010, 7, 3),
           datetime.date(2010, 7, 10), datetime.date(2010, 7, 16),
           datetime.date(2010, 7, 22), datetime.date(2010, 7, 26),
           datetime.date(2010, 7, 28), datetime.date(2010, 7, 30),
           datetime.date(2010, 8, 1), datetime.date(2010, 8, 7),
           datetime.date(2010, 8, 23), datetime.date(2010, 8, 24),
           datetime.date(2010, 9, 2), datetime.date(2010, 9, 12),
           datetime.date(2010, 9, 27), datetime.date(2010, 9, 29),
           datetime.date(2010, 9, 30), datetime.date(2010, 10, 2),
           datetime.date(2010, 10, 3), datetime.date(2010, 10, 15),
           datetime.date(2010, 10, 16), datetime.date(2010, 10, 25),
           datetime.date(2010, 10, 26), datetime.date(2010, 10, 27),
           datetime.date(2010, 10, 29), datetime.date(2010, 11, 2),
           datetime.date(2010, 11, 3), datetime.date(2010, 11, 4),
           datetime.date(2010, 11, 5), datetime.date(2010, 11, 6),
           datetime.date(2010, 11, 7), datetime.date(2010, 11, 9),
           datetime.date(2010, 11, 12), datetime.date(2010, 11, 16),
           datetime.date(2010, 11, 17), datetime.date(2010, 11, 26),
           datetime.date(2010, 11, 27), datetime.date(2010, 11, 28),
           datetime.date(2010, 11, 29), datetime.date(2010, 11, 30),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 1), datetime.date(2010, 12, 2),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 4), datetime.date(2010, 12, 5),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 6), datetime.date(2010, 12, 7),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 11), datetime.date(2010, 12, 12),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 13), datetime.date(2010, 12, 14),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 16), datetime.date(2010, 12, 17),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 18), datetime.date(2010, 12, 19),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 20), datetime.date(2010, 12, 22),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 23), datetime.date(2010, 12, 24),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 26), datetime.date(2010, 12, 27),
           datetime.date(2010, 12, 28)], dtype=object)

    In [4]: ais.head()

    Out[4]:
        MMSI    LAT     LON     COURSE_OVER_GROUND  NAV_STATUS  POS_ACCURACY    RATE_OF_TURN    SPEED_OVER_GROUND   HEADING
    TX_DTTM                                     
    2010-01-01 00:00:19     12345678    32.834746   -79.929589  1820    0   0   128     71  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:00:29     12345678    32.834384   -79.929602  1832    0   0   128     71  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:00:40     12345678    32.834058   -79.929619  1836    0   0   128     70  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:00:50     12345678    32.833703   -79.929647  1847    0   0   128     70  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:01:00     12345678    32.833386   -79.929689  1897    0   0   128     69  NaN

    In [5]: unique(ais.index.date)

    Out[5]:

    array([datetime.date(2010, 1, 1), datetime.date(2010, 1, 4),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 5), datetime.date(2010, 1, 6),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 7), datetime.date(2010, 1, 8),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 9), datetime.date(2010, 1, 10),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 11), datetime.date(2010, 1, 12),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 13), datetime.date(2010, 1, 14),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 15), datetime.date(2010, 1, 16),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 17), datetime.date(2010, 1, 18),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 19), datetime.date(2010, 1, 20),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 21), datetime.date(2010, 1, 22),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 23), datetime.date(2010, 1, 24),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 25), datetime.date(2010, 1, 26),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 27), datetime.date(2010, 1, 28),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 29), datetime.date(2010, 1, 30),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 31), datetime.date(2010, 2, 1)], dtype=object)

    In [6]: len(ais)

    Out[6]: 2750499

    In [7]: ais[Index(ais.index.date).isin(Index(thresh_eval.index.date))]

    Out[7]:
        MMSI    LAT     LON     COURSE_OVER_GROUND  NAV_STATUS  POS_ACCURACY    RATE_OF_TURN    SPEED_OVER_GROUND   HEADING
    TX_DTTM                                     
    2010-01-01 00:00:19     12345678    32.834746   -79.929589  1820    0   0   128     71  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:00:29     12345678    32.834384   -79.929602  1832    0   0   128     71  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:00:40     12345678    32.834058   -79.929619  1836    0   0   128     70  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:00:50     12345678    32.833703   -79.929647  1847    0   0   128     70  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:01:00     12345678    32.833386   -79.929689  1897    0   0   128     69  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:01:06     12345678    32.833106   -79.929757  1934    0   0   128     69  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:01:16     12345678    32.832830   -79.929850  1978    0   0   128     69  NaN
    2010-01-01 00:01:26     12345678    32.832495   -79.929990  2010    0   0   128     69  NaN

    In [8]: len(ais)

    Out[8]: 2750499

    In [9]: unique(ais.index.date)

    Out[9]:

    array([datetime.date(2010, 1, 1), datetime.date(2010, 1, 4),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 5), datetime.date(2010, 1, 6),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 7), datetime.date(2010, 1, 8),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 9), datetime.date(2010, 1, 10),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 11), datetime.date(2010, 1, 12),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 13), datetime.date(2010, 1, 14),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 15), datetime.date(2010, 1, 16),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 17), datetime.date(2010, 1, 18),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 19), datetime.date(2010, 1, 20),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 21), datetime.date(2010, 1, 22),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 23), datetime.date(2010, 1, 24),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 25), datetime.date(2010, 1, 26),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 27), datetime.date(2010, 1, 28),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 29), datetime.date(2010, 1, 30),
           datetime.date(2010, 1, 31), datetime.date(2010, 2, 1)], dtype=object)
```

**Original problem:**
I'm trying to subset a dataframe based on a comparison between its datetime index, and the datetime index of another data frame.  df1 is a dataframe of downsampled timeseries to use as a filter.  df2 is a dataframe of records to be filtered, which has higher temporal resolution, and multiple records per date appearing in df1:

```
In [1]: df1
    Out[1]:
                 WSPD        cd
    date                           
    2010-07-10  11.325645  0.000019
    2010-08-23  12.258462  0.000019
    2010-11-09  10.771429  0.000019
    2010-11-12  10.650000  0.000019
    2010-11-16  11.939535  0.000019
    ...

    In [2]: df2
    Out[2]:
                             ID   Latitude  Longitude  Course  RateOfTurn  
    TimeStamp                                                                  
    2010-06-26 22:36:11  311425000  32.832500 -79.929000       3           0   
    2010-06-26 22:36:21  311425000  32.832845 -79.929037       3           0   
    2010-06-26 22:36:32  311425000  32.833333 -79.929000       3           0   
    2010-06-26 22:36:42  311425000  32.833666 -79.929000       3           0 
    2010-07-10 07:37:21  548723000  32.832333 -79.929000     1.0           0   
    2010-07-10 07:37:31  548723000  32.832666 -79.929000     1.0           0   
    2010-07-10 07:37:40  548723000  32.833000 -79.929000     2.0           0   
    2010-07-10 07:37:51  548723000  32.833333 -79.929000     1.0           0   
    2010-07-10 07:38:04  548723000  32.833666 -79.929000     0.0           0   
    2010-08-23 09:29:48  311425000  32.832590 -79.928985     0.0           0   
    2010-08-23 09:30:00  311425000  32.833053 -79.928970     1.0           0   
    2010-08-23 09:30:10  311425000  32.833443 -79.928957     1.0           0   
    2010-08-23 09:30:18  311425000  32.833746 -79.928944     2.0           0   
    ...

    In [3]: list = []
            for i,item in enumerate(df2.index.date): 
                if item in df1.index.date:
                    list.append(item)

    In [4]: list
    out[4]: [datetime.date(2010, 8, 23),
     datetime.date(2010, 8, 23),
     datetime.date(2010, 8, 23),
     datetime.date(2010, 8, 23),
     datetime.date(2010, 7, 10),
     datetime.date(2010, 7, 10),
     datetime.date(2010, 7, 10),
     datetime.date(2010, 7, 10),
     datetime.date(2010, 7, 10)]
```

I'm losing the contents beyond the index.  I'd really like a subset of records from df2, including all data, that have datetimes matching df1 at the day frequency, like:

```
    2010-07-10 07:37:21  548723000  32.832333 -79.929000     1.0           0   
    2010-07-10 07:37:31  548723000  32.832666 -79.929000     1.0           0   
    2010-07-10 07:37:40  548723000  32.833000 -79.929000     2.0           0   
    2010-07-10 07:37:51  548723000  32.833333 -79.929000     1.0           0   
    2010-07-10 07:38:04  548723000  32.833666 -79.929000     0.0           0   
    2010-08-23 09:29:48  311425000  32.832590 -79.928985     0.0           0   
    2010-08-23 09:30:00  311425000  32.833053 -79.928970     1.0           0   
    2010-08-23 09:30:10  311425000  32.833443 -79.928957     1.0           0   
    2010-08-23 09:30:18  311425000  32.833746 -79.928944     2.0           0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `isin` method:

```
In [33]: import datetime

In [34]: import pandas as pd

In [35]: from pandas import DataFrame, Index

In [36]: from numpy.random import randn, unique, array

In [37]: df1 = DataFrame({'lat': randn(48), 'long': randn(48)}, index=pd.date_range('2013-01-02',periods=4
8,freq='H'))

In [38]: df2 = DataFrame({'lat': randn(72), 'long': randn(72)}, index=pd.date_range('2013-01-02',periods=7
2,freq='H'))

In [39]: df1.head()
Out[39]:
                        lat    long
2013-01-02 00:00:00  0.7310  0.3083
2013-01-02 01:00:00  1.8540  0.7355
2013-01-02 02:00:00  0.3097 -0.1834
2013-01-02 03:00:00  0.8455  0.8350
2013-01-02 04:00:00  0.4017  0.0559

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [40]: df2.head()
Out[40]:
                        lat    long
2013-01-02 00:00:00  1.4248  0.2289
2013-01-02 01:00:00 -0.5055  0.1072
2013-01-02 02:00:00 -1.8265 -1.0651
2013-01-02 03:00:00  0.5888  0.3992
2013-01-02 04:00:00 -1.5210  0.0710

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [41]: df2[Index(df2.index.date).isin(Index(df1.index.date))]
Out[41]:
                        lat    long
2013-01-02 00:00:00  1.4248  0.2289
2013-01-02 01:00:00 -0.5055  0.1072
2013-01-02 02:00:00 -1.8265 -1.0651
2013-01-02 03:00:00  0.5888  0.3992
2013-01-02 04:00:00 -1.5210  0.0710
2013-01-02 05:00:00  0.8382 -1.5569
2013-01-02 06:00:00 -0.7878  0.9253
2013-01-02 07:00:00 -0.1686 -1.0128
2013-01-02 08:00:00 -0.2481 -0.4247
2013-01-02 09:00:00  0.0794 -0.1947
2013-01-02 10:00:00 -0.5046 -0.1535
2013-01-02 11:00:00  0.0696 -1.5125
2013-01-02 12:00:00  1.1984 -0.1880
2013-01-02 13:00:00  0.8251 -0.2588
2013-01-02 14:00:00  1.5858 -1.2998
2013-01-02 15:00:00  0.2727 -0.3030
2013-01-02 16:00:00  0.9459 -0.8018
2013-01-02 17:00:00 -1.5055 -1.1344
2013-01-02 18:00:00  0.3970  0.7449
2013-01-02 19:00:00 -1.0256  0.2245
2013-01-02 20:00:00  0.8322  0.6473
2013-01-02 21:00:00  0.2759  1.4096
2013-01-02 22:00:00 -0.5167  1.5676
2013-01-02 23:00:00  0.4620  0.4936
2013-01-03 00:00:00  1.4400  0.5696
                        ...     ...

[48 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can check that the result only contains date indices where they overlap on the day frequency by comparing

```
In [42]: unique(df2[Index(df2.index.date).isin(Index(df1.index.date))].index.date)
Out[42]: array([datetime.date(2013, 1, 2), datetime.date(2013, 1, 3)], dtype=object)

In [43]: unique(df1.index.date)
Out[43]: array([datetime.date(2013, 1, 2), datetime.date(2013, 1, 3)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'm attempting to implement something similar to this, but am getting hung up at df2[Index(df2.index.date).isin(Index(df1.index.date))], which throws the error:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4806e9edb789> in <module>()
----> 1 df2[Index(df2.index.date).isin(Index(df1.index.date))]

NameError: name 'Index' is not defined

Comment: You need to do `from pandas import Index`.

Comment: I'll add the necessary imports to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it will work much better.  The last solution I came up with prior to this looks like: `df2_sub = [i for i,item in enumerate(df2.index.date) if item in df1.index.date]`
`new_df2= pd.DataFrame(ais.ix[ais_sub])` Which is sloppy code and fairly inefficient.  Each of my files to be filtered is about 1M records.

Comment: Last comment was inaccurate.  point is the code was not good.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I had made cosmetic changes to keep code in df1, df2 context. I missed renaming some variables: new_df2=pd.DataFrame(ais.ix[ais_sub]). ais_sub is a subset of ais (df1) that I made with the filter (df2). I assigned that to a variable, and then cast the variable as a dataframe called new_df2. It works, but it's an iterative solution, and takes a significant amount of time to run on large data sets.  Your version appears to be array wise, and does in 1 line of code what I did in 3.  I implemented your solution but it's not subsetting.  Updated code in the original problem.

Comment: Can you show the output of what you're getting from what you implemented? Thx

Comment: I expanded that - Output is now in out [7]. Out[8] and out[9] are for verification.